# about the sum of multiple select in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to have sum of some queries from the same table. the queries are like these:

```
    select sum(credit) from member_a where mno=5 and transtype='xyz'
    select sum(credit) from member_a where mno=5 and transtype='abcd'
    select sum(credit) from member_a where mno=5 and transtype='psr'
```

I need to have total of the above three queries.

Thanks

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Rig: What is wrong with this question exactly?

Comment: @musefan Well basically it shows no effort on the questioners behalf, so it looks like a `Do It For Me` question

Comment: @musefan How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Rig: What do you mean no effort? The OP has already worked out how to sum values and to filter on the `transtype` they want, they are just missing the final piece that combines them all together... if the OP put any more effort in they would have posted the answer in the question!

Comment: I new to sql server. Tried to solve the issues several time from several sources. But failed. that's why posted here.

Answer (score 4):

You can put all your condition together in a WHERE clause, using AND/OR (and in this case IN too)

```
   SELECT SUM(CREDIT) AS TOTAL_CREDIT
    FROM member_a where mno=5 and transtype IN('xyz','abcd','psr')
```

Comment: Please put some effort in to expand on this answer and explain what the OP was doing wrong and what you have changed to resolve it. A code only answer is pretty lame, and I would remove my upvote if I could. I upvoted assuming you was going to improve your answer, my mistake clearly

Comment: @musefan usually I explain, but here it's very very simple question and answer.   I think you can remove your upvote and do it if you want.  I think SO changed a lot since beginning...

Comment: @etsa: If the question and answer was so simple the OP would not have asked the question. You should base your answers on the level of the OP, not on your own understanding and experience. Also I could remove upvote because it had been 10 minutes since upvote and requires an edit (which you have obviously now done)

Comment: @musefan that's your thought, but I don't agree completely with you: as I said I think SO (and SO user changed a lot since some years ago).